# What is the best way to programatically load data into MemSQL from S3 or Azure?

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, singlestore

I have to load data (in the form of CSV or TSV) from some path in Amazon S3 bucket into some MemSQL tables. In future loading data from Azure blob storage may be required. There are two ways, that I know, to do it:

- MemSQL Pipeline
- MemSQL Loader (Depricated)

Here are the pros and cons of the two approaches which needs to be considered:

- **MemSQL** **Pipeline** - If we manually create the pipeline, then it will automatically keep doing the job. However, keeping the pipeline always in running state will waste the system resources (RAM). Also new files, containing the data to be loaded in MemSQL, will be added to S3 only at specific time of the day (through some cron job). So, I want to programatically create the pipeline (using JDBC) if it doesn't exist, start the pipeline and then stop it after all the data is loaded successfully (also handle the errors if any during the process). This process will run as a daily cron job.
  However I couldn't find any way to know if all the data is synced up or not. Also I couldn't find any good way to know if any error occurred in the process.
- **MemSQL** **Loader** - MemSQL loader does send the status after it has completed loading the desired data. So, I can perform the above mentioned job inside a cron job. However, since MemSQL loader is deprecated now, so, I don't want to use it.

Please suggest the best way to load the data to MemSQL tables. Also, please let me know if there are other ways to do the same (apart from pipeline and loader).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given one is deprecated, and the other isn't, your choice should be clear... use the one that is not deprecated.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel For MemSQL pipeline I also said, "I couldn't find any way to know if all the data is synced up or not. Also I couldn't find any good way to know if any error occurred in the process". Please help me how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

MemSQL Pipelines ares the right fit for your workload. As you mentioned, S3 and Azure Pipelines will automatically load new files for you as they become available. When the Pipeline is not loading data, it will not use system resources other than an extremely small amount of metadata. This is specifically designed so that you do not need to manually set up a chron job to load your data. If necessary, you can also stop loading new files via the [`STOP PIPELINE`](https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.0/stop-pipeline/) command.

There are tables in the information_schema database which will allow you to see the status of all your pipelines and all errors that have been hit. Specfically, you would want to query the [`PIPELINES_ERRORS`](https://docs.memsql.com/memsql-pipelines/v6.0/pipelines-information-schema-tables/#information-schema-pipelines-errors-table) table to get errors.